# Query a list of objects in dynamodb

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to get a result from my **dynamodb** database and ran into a problem, I have this data in my *orders* table.

```json
{
    "orders": [
      {
        "id": "24950-05675",
        "orderNumber": null,
        "orderProduct": [
          {
            "id": "28",
            "relatedProductsID": null,
            "quantity": 1
          },
          {
            "id": "31",
            "relatedProductsID": null,
            "quantity": 2
          },
          {
            "id": "99",
            "relatedProductsID": null,
            "quantity": 3
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

and I trying to query for the values inside **orderProduct** attribute as you can see is a list of objects, so am using *FilterExpression* with *contains* in my query like this.

> productId  = `{id: '28'}`

```js
   let attributes = {
            country: { String: ':country', Name: 'country', Value: country },
            orderProduct: { String: ':orderProduct', Name: 'orderProduct', Value: productId }
        };
        const { query } = this.generateQueryFull(attributes);
        let params = this._createParamObject({
            IndexName: 'countryIndex',
            KeyConditionExpression: query.string,
            ConditionExpression: 'enabled = true',
            ExpressionAttributeNames: query.atributeNames,
            ExpressionAttributeValues: query.atributeValues,
            FilterExpression: 'contains(#orderProduct, :orderProduct)'
        });
```

and running with `query` like this:

```js
let response = await this.dbService.client
            .query(params)
            .promise();
```

The query is generating without problems and the consult is executing correctly.
So the idea is to filter in the list `orderProduct` by the propertie `{ id: <string>}`, I have done this before without problem with object lists, but when I try this implementation I don't get results but also don't get any error.

I do not know what I can be doing wrong if someone has an idea it would be very helpful.

the final `query`

[image]

`query` string

```json
{"string":"#country = :country","atributeNames":"#country":"country","#orderProduct":"orderProduct"},"atributeValues":{":country":"co",":orderProduct":{"id":"31"}}}
```

Comment: Can you show what the "query" object looks like? It's hard to know what is wrong without seeing that. It also would be helpful to know the partition key, and sort key if there is one.

Comment: sure, I've already uploaded a picture with the query object

Comment: The query object isn't valid JSON. It's difficult to know what is going on without the full picture of what the data is. You are showing an object in the first JSON, but that clearly isn't the entire object, because you are querying on "country" in your key. The more information you can provide the more likely it is that someone can help you. Feel free to remove data that is irrelevant, but include anything that is referenced in other parts of the question.